# ERROR TypeError: this.signaturePad.set is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, signaturepad

I am developing an angular6 project with ngx-signaturepad. I followed the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-signaturepad but I am getting the error
'ERROR TypeError: this.signaturePad.set is not a function
'
and not showing the sign pad in my project.

```
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'ngx-signaturepad';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [ SignaturePadModule ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

// then import for use in a component

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SignaturePad } from 'ngx-signaturepad/signature-pad';

@Component({
  template: '<signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>'
})

export class SignaturePadPage{

  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;

  private signaturePadOptions: Object = { // passed through to szimek/signature_pad constructor
    'minWidth': 5,
    'canvasWidth': 500,
    'canvasHeight': 300
  };

  constructor() {
    // no-op
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.signaturePad is now available
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 5); // set szimek/signature_pad options at runtime
    this.signaturePad.clear(); // invoke functions from szimek/signature_pad API
  }

  drawComplete() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onEnd event
    console.log(this.signaturePad.toDataURL());
  }

  drawStart() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onBegin event
    console.log('begin drawing');
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd try two things. The first one, assigning an ID to the element in the template such as #signaturePad and then referencing it on the ViewChild declaration. Something like this

```
@Component({
  template: '<signature-pad #signaturePanel [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>'
})

export class SignaturePadPage{

  @ViewChild("signaturePanel") signaturePad: SignaturePad;
...
```

Seems that the problem is that your variable is not initializing correctly. This can happen because of the wrong referencing, or maybe it is initializing time after the component shows. You may try to add a setTimeout to the ngAfterViewInit to check if this is happening. Something like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 5); // set szimek/signature_pad options at runtime
    this.signaturePad.clear(); // invoke functions from szimek/signature_pad API
},1000) //After 1 Second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect  may not be fully initialized when you attempt to set the width. Instead of calling in the `AfterViewInit` method, leverage the `onBeginEvent` event.  An example is provided below.

````
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'ngx-signaturepad';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ],
  imports: [ SignaturePadModule ],
  providers: [ ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

// then import for use in a component

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SignaturePad } from 'ngx-signaturepad/signature-pad';

@Component({
  template: '<signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" (onBeginEvent)="drawStart()" (onEndEvent)="drawComplete()"></signature-pad>'
})

export class SignaturePadPage{

  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;

  private signaturePadOptions: Object = { // passed through to szimek/signature_pad constructor
    'minWidth': 5,
    'canvasWidth': 500,
    'canvasHeight': 300
  };

  constructor() {
    // no-op
  }

  drawComplete() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onEnd event
    console.log(this.signaturePad.toDataURL());
  }

  drawStart() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onBegin event
    console.log('begin drawing');
    this.configureSignaturePad();
  }

  private configureSignaturePad() {
    // this.signaturePad is now available
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 5); // set szimek/signature_pad options at runtime
    this.signaturePad.clear(); // invoke functions from szimek/signature_pad API
  }
}```
````

Comment: Signature pad not visible both the method